# Is there any standard formats available for test cases other than table?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, testcase

I've written some test cases, but the only thing I know is the format of a table (with the expected results, actual results, pass/fail etc). Is there any standard formats available for test cases?

Comment: The format is usually given to you by the tools you are using.

Answer (score 3):

There are many forms how test cases can be written in, one popular format is the Gherkins syntax:

```
 Scenario: Some determinable business situation
      Given some precondition
        And some other precondition
      When some action by the actor
       And some other action
       And yet another action
     Then some testable outcome is achieved
       And something else we can check happens too
```

It is more business friendly, for more information, please click [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin).

Comment: I've just wondered if Gherkins syntax is applicable for NUnit environment. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I would look into Junit, Xunit and NUnit

*XUnit is the family name given to bunch of testing frameworks that have become widely known amongst software developers. The name is a derivation of JUnit, the first of these to be widely known.*

Check more details at [martinfowler](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/Xunit.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'm using NUnit for a plenty of time, and also found it very useful

Answer (score 0):

Specflow is Gherkin implementainion on C#, which generates tests methods written using NUnit, MSTest, xUnit among other available unit test providers. 
You could read [this answer from stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918055/nunit-framework-vs-specflow-framework)